# How to get the name of Xamarin.Forms element from object?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Views like `Button`, `Entry`, `Label`, `Picker` and so on can have a `x:Name` attribute.

```xml
<Label x:Name="myLabelName" Text="Some text" />
```

`x` is defined as `xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"`.

Now I want to work with unclassified items and therefore I use `object` as type.

How do I get the `x:Name` attribute as string in code from a `object`? I don't know the type at this stage.

**Edit:**

To make things more clear I want to post some code. I have a normal XAML page like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="XamlSamples.HelloXamlPage">
    <Label x:Name="myLabelName" Text="Some text" />
</ContentPage>
```

In the code-behind file I can get the `x:Name` attribute if I do `nameof(this.myLabelName)`. But how is this done if you have `object` only?

```cs
public partial class HelloXamlPage
{
    public HelloXamlPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<string> itemsWhichPassTheCheck = this.Check(new List<object>() { this.myLabelName });
    }
}

private List<string> Check(List<object> itemList)
{
    // do some check here ...
    // here I have only object and I want to get the x:Name attribute thereof
}
```

Comment: When you want get the attribute name of elements. i mean while event or when loading?

Comment: Don't know exactly what you mean. The user presses a button and then I want to make some checks. Here I would need access to the name attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm 100% sure there's a way to refactor your code to avoid the need you have, but for the sake of answering, here's how you could get the name of any objects:

We know for sure that any object tagged with `x:Name` will create a field of the same name.

So, using reflection, you should be able to get all the fields defined in your page, compare them against your object, and return the field name if it matches.

I haven't tested this, but that should work, or at least put you on the right track

```cs
string GetNameOf(object topLevelXaml, object reference)
{
    var fields = topLevelXaml.GetType().GetFields();
    foreach (var fi in fields) {
        var value = fi.GetValue(topLevelXaml);
        if (value != reference)
            continue;
        return fi.Name;
    }
    return null;
}
```

But again, you shouldn't probably need this at all.

Comment: I get *'ReflectionExtensions.GetFields(Type)' is inaccessible due to its protection level*. Now I use `GetRuntimeFields()` instead and I get the name. For `topLevelXaml` I use `this` (the current page). But you are right, I'll rethink my approach.

Answer (score 0):

As a variant in .xaml use both with the same:
x:Name="example" ClassID="example"

in .cs:
Label gotNext = (Label)FindByName(gotLabel.ClassId)

in my situation example was:
void Feature_Tapped(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)

```
        Label gotLabel = sender as Label;
        Label gotNext = (Label)FindByName(gotLabel.ClassId+"a");
```